# Magento Most Viewed Products: What condition should be met?

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

As Magento keep track on several logs or reports. One of them is Most viewed items. 
I am not sure what conditions should met for one product to be in most viewed items.

> How long a product must be viewed to have it into most viewed?

I got this query from one of my client and I checked files for answer but did not get any correct one.

Hope I did not miss any part of Magento documentation which may give answer of this question.

Suggestions appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below steps :
Step 1: 
Go to app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Product/Viewed/Collection.php

Copy the file to app/code/local/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Product/Viewed/Collection.php

Step 2: protected $_ratingLimit        = 5;

Comment: Yes @Yuvraj Let me check if it works.

Comment: It works. @yuvraj

Answer (score 0):

The condition for most viewed product is number of views. You can find reports in table like report_viewed_product_index. It records everytime a product is viewed. 
Then you can get a collection of most viewed products and limit by items that you want to show. You can try the following code:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->addViewsCount()
->setPageSize($totalPerPage);
```

Hope it helps!